# Android: Starting a service at a chosen time

Tags: java, android, android-service, alarmmanager, android-calendar

I have a BroadcastReceiver starting a service. In this service I have an AlarmManager I want to start another service at a certain time of day, every day.

The BroadcastReceiver starts when I open the app, but the AlarmManager only starts its service if I start the BroadCastReceiver at the set time.

How do I get it to continuously compare the present time to the set time, so that it will automatically run when the time is right?

In MainActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = new Intent();   
    intent.setAction("com.example.BroadcastPro.MyBroadcastReceiver");   
    sendBroadcast(intent);  
}
```

In myBroadcastReceiver.java

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        Intent  i=new Intent(context,SetPeriodicService.class);    
        context.startService(i);
    }
}
```

In SetPeriodicService.java

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)    
{
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);  

    Intent i=new Intent(this,MyService.class);  
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), alarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);    
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't quite clear: does `MyService' not get started on schedule if `SetPeriodicService` is running? Can't you simply start the new service at the desired time by posting a delayed runnable from the old service?

Comment: @user87049 No, MyService does not start unless I run the app exactly on the set time.

Answer (score 0):

In SetPeriodicService.java at `alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), alarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);`
You need change to `alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), alarmMgr.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);`